# File management in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a file storing and management system. There are two options

1. When i create a folder i actually make a directory of same name in uploads folder and then manage files in those individual separate folders.
   like

   ```
   Uploads
     |
   folder 1
    |-file 1
    |-file 2
   folder 2
     |folder 3
     |-file 3
   ```
2. When i create a folder i don't actually create it in my uploads folder, but insert it as a database entry. And upload all files in a single uploads folder.

   ```
   Uploads
     |-file 1
     |file 2
     |file 3
   ```

Folders in database

Which option would be better? Any suggestions?

Comment: What pros and cons of each approach can _you_ think of?

Comment: @CBroe the second option will need less code as no directory will be made. First looks better when i need to look for a particular file i can serach it in the software and manually too by opening that particular directory. I want opinion of an expert so i can start building . what do you think which ones better approach?

Comment: How many files do you plan to insert ? 50 ? 5,000 ? 500,000 ?

Comment: @Thibault dint think of a number.. say 5000+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution #1:

- better if you want to access the files in a normal filemanager like
  windows explorer

Solution #2:

- difficult to handle duplicate files
- easier to implement

Just to give you an idea...

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert but I think the first solution is for a personal use, I mean if the this management system is intended to be useb only by you, or few people as it will cost a lot of memory and CPU than the second solution.

you can even go further with the seconde solution using tables index etc to make it faster.

the duplication problem is not that hard, you can use file hash for exemple as unique field in the table.